# msbuild Dotfuscator exec task giving error MSB3073 exited with code 1

Tags: msbuild, dotfuscator

Am trying to run dotfuscator via an Exec task using MSBuild. It gives a msb3073 exited with code 1 , any ideas or suggestions on further troubleshooting appreciated.

Following is the command in the target file:

```
<Target>
<Exec Command="%22$(ObfuscatorExe)%22 /q /p=AppPath=%22$(TargetDir.TrimEnd('\'))%22,ObfuscatedDll=%22$(TargetFileName)%22,PackageDir=%22$(ModuleDir)%22 %22$(PathOfDotFuscatorXml)%22"  />    
</Target>
```

The command gets translated as below.

error MSB3073: The command `""C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation 4.35.0\dotfuscator.exe" /q /p=PluginPath="<dlloutputpath>",ObfuscatedDll="<dllname>",PackageDir="<packageDir>" "<path to dotfuscator.xml>""` exited with code 1.

I have a feeling the extra quotes at the start and the end is causing this problem , because if i try to run this command on the dotfuscator command line , i am able to get the command working.
Additionally the MSBuild build output is set to diagnostic.

Comment: I saw this post because I work on the Dotfuscator team. I'm not able to reproduce your issue with the information provided; does the MSBuild output list anything from Dotfuscator? You might consider removing the quiet flag (`/q`) to get the most information possible about what's happening before the error. Finally, given that you're using an evaluation of Professional Edition, you can contact PreEmptive's support, which can be handy if you don't want to share more details on a public forum like StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for your reply. I was able to solve this issue by moving the profiles to the network service authority folder within the build machine. However i have another issue , dotfuscator now runs successfully on the specified dlls. But however when i disassemble the code using ildasm or a sample piece of code using System.Reflection i am not able to see the dotfuscator attribute coming up. Can you please help on this regard. Please share me your email id for me to share the details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014338/dotfuscator-pro-cant-read-licensing-information-under-jenkins-buildserver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa Many thanks to hubert for his post.

Comment: Could you share the details of your problem with our support team? https://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform